# Multiple onActivityResult for 1 Activity using Zxing barcode

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, zxing

I am developing a simple app that collect asset data from pc which each of the asset has two barcodes.The barcodes is serial number and model number.The form contain 2 textview and 3 buttons.Each textview to return the result of each scan.While,2 of the buttons for scan the barcodes and 1 button for submit the result of the scans to database.

The code below is work well but when i use any "scan", the buttons always returns the result to the first textview which serial number.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String scannedData;
TextView  contentTxt;
TextView  contentTxt2;

Button scanBtnSerial;
Button scanBtnModel;


//Button viewBtn;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Activity activity =this;
    scanBtnSerial = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);//to scan serial number
    scanBtnModel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan2_btn);//to scan model number

    contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);//to view scanned serial number
    contentTxt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);//to view scanned model number

    final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    scanBtnSerial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan Serial Number");
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });

    scanBtnModel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan Model Number");
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(result!=null) {
        scannedData = result.getContents();
        if (scannedData != null) {

            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            contentTxt.setText(result.getContents());
            new SendRequest().execute();//send to database 


        }else {
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can i manage "onActivityResult" 's to show data for each scan ?

[UI sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqU6L.png)

Comment: I added the ZXIng way of solving this to the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and easy approach would be to replace this part in `onActivityResult`

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
contentTxt.setText(result.getContents());
new SendRequest().execute();//send to database
```

with

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(contextText.getText())){
    contentTxt.setText(result.getContents());
} else {
    contentTxt2.setText(result.getContents());
}
new SendRequest().execute();//send to database
```

However, this is most probably not what you want/need. You should differentiate the inputs you get in the result and assign them to appropriate `TextView`s.

If your codes have different, predefined formats, **consider using a regexp** to identify which one was scanned and assign it to the correct `TextView`. Android has a helper class called [Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), check it out.

The resulting code would probably look like this:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
if(isSerialNumberString(result.getContents())){
    contentTxt.setText(result.getContents());
} else if(isModelNumberString(result.getContents())) {
    contentTxt2.setText(result.getContents());
}
new SendRequest().execute();//send to database
```

If not, **consider using a setup flow**, where you ask the user to first scan one code, put it in the UI, and then ask them to scan the second. This way you will know which code you are expecting at the moment.

---

EDIT:
It turns out `ZXing` has a mechanism for that. So, there are two things you will need to do:

First, add custom request codes to your `Integrators`. So the ScanBtnSerial's `OnClickListener` will look like this:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
integrator.setRequestCode(1) //Make this a constant        
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setPrompt("Scan Model Number");
```

Do the same for the other OnClickListener, just set 2 as the requestCode.

Then, in the `onResult` method, do this:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
if(requestCode == 1) { //Again, use a const here
    contentTxt.setText(result.getContents());
} else if(requestCode == 2) {
    contentTxt2.setText(result.getContents());
}
new SendRequest().execute();//send to database
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,i got more sight about the activity thing.But,why it show error cannot resolve method setRequestCode?Do ineed to create the method first?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by either setting a global boolean to remember which activity has started, or set an appropriate requestCode like so https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/41